# Symfony unexplainable foreach error, without having any foreach

Tags: php, symfony, foreach

None of the suggested questions apply for this case, because I don't have any foreach in my code but the error code keep saying that..

My action is:

```
public function doctrinoAction()
    {
        $id=1;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $dql = 'SELECT p FROM TPMainBundle:Works p WHERE p.id = :id';
        $consulta = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameters('id', $id);
        $productos = $consulta->getResult();
        return $this->render('TPMainBundle:Default:indra.html.php', array(
                    'productos' => $productos,
        ));
    }
```

And my View is just:

```
<?php
echo 'lio';
```

NO foreach.
I could write anything in the view, and the error code will be the same.
I could send the render to any view that it doesn't reach it, the error code is:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\TP\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query.php line 303
```

And I'm working in dev, and cleared the cache.. What is happening?

The only existing 'foreach' loop, is the one located at that "Query.php" file, but It's not created by me.

Line 303 of query.php:

```
foreach ($this->parameters as $parameter) {
        $key    = $parameter->getName();
        $value  = $parameter->getValue();
```

Please help

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32020390/3933332

Comment: Man, I deleted it because I have problems updating it.
I thought it was better to create this one, with the accurate info

Comment: Thanks for nothing :( you didn't help me in the other post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
$consulta = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameters('id', $id);
```

To this:

```
$consulta = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('id', $id);
```

Or to this:

```
$params = array('id' => $id);
$consulta = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameters($params);
```

Comment: Are you God? It worked.. i mean the third option (1 and 2 are the same).
Can you please provide me with some explanation so I can understand the problem behind ?  Bless you, my ass hurts from being sit trying to make this work

Comment: Both are methods of `\Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder`. Compare [`setParameter()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L530) and [`setParameters()`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L572) you'll see the latter has a foreach loop, and expects either some sort of collection (I assume `ArrayCollection` or an array.

Comment: @lio89 1st and 2nd are not the same. 1st is how you were doing, and the second is `setParameter` (without `s` at the end). The third is the function you were using, but using an array, as the function expects. Read more: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query Good to know this helped!